# how to join two tables in database Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to join two tables (products table and Images table), so in products table each product has multiple images(stored in a row named image) so I want to display images of each product in `images table`. In images table I have a foreign key named `product_id` references(id) on products table, The problem is it can't store images in images table,(it keeps storing images in the row(image) in products table). How do I solve this?

Codes

Product.php

```
public function images()
 {
   return $this->hasMany('App\Image', 'product_id');
 }
```

Image.php

```
public function product()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Product','product_id');
 }
```

Controller

```
 public function store(Request $request) 
 { 

$Input=$request->all();
$image=array();
if($files=$request->file('image')){
foreach($files as $file){
    $name=$file->getClientOriginalName();
    $file->move('images',$name);
    $image[]=$name;
  }
  } 
 product::create(array_merge($Input,
 [
 'image' => json_encode($image),

 ])); 
return redirect()->back(); 

}
```

Any help will be appriciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to save the image to the images table, and you are instead 'it keeps storing images in the row(image) in products table' - you are saving the wrong item.  You appear to have the correct structure - with one to many in your models.  Just need to save the **Image** rather than the **Product**

Something *like this* will fix this issue:

```
Image::create(['whateverYouNeedToSave', 
              'product_id'=>$product_id,      <-- Connect the product here, within the image
              'etc']);
```

It is actually possible to do this by creating the **Product** and then saving the **Images** as a relation, but this might not be the cleanest / easiest way to architect this - suggest you start with saving the **Image**, as you will have many of them, vs. just one **Product** at a time.  Then, after this works, and is clear / comfortable, you can try it the more 'advanced' way if you need to.

Comment: If you already have a product created, use that id that you want to attach the image to.  If you don't and this is a new product, create the product first, get it's id, then make all the images for the images that attach to the product, using that new product id.  This is not the most efficient, but it will help you to troubleshoot / understand how it can work.  Eventually you can bring in relationships and `attach()` the images to that new product.

Comment: In my form I cant create a product without adding image, so products table has fillable[price,name,image etc.] @Watercayman

Comment: If you can have many images per product, I'm not sure why you would have a single image field on the product.  The one to many would sit on the image (product_id) and not on the product.  I think you need to double check your database structure.

Comment: why am I getting this error `"Undefined variable: product_id"`

Comment: Did you define `$product_id` after creating (or using an old product), like I said in the first comment?

Comment: No, I didn't define it that function is what creates the product.

Comment: I have just remove the `image` row from products table now if I dd($input) , it shows the product details and images but , doesn't store in database (images table).

Comment: OK, create the product.  Get the id from the product.  Create the images using the new product id as the foreign key.   You need to actually write the code something like my answer in order for it to write to the db.  Now that you've removed the image field from the product, this will work as a demo / help you to understand.